# Eclipse : shift + 8 button is not working

Tags: eclipse, keyboard

I am facing issues with keyboard specifically in Eclipse. I wanted to put multi line comment using /** but using **"SHIFT + 8"** is not working at all. It wont print anything. If we simply press 8 button it does print 8.

In fact I tried other combinations like **"SHIFT + 1 "** -> prints ! (Exclamation mark). It works perfectly fine in Eclipse.

Surprisingly,  I tried **"SHIFT + 8 "** in other applications It works perfectly. I dont understand why this only SHIFT + 8 is not working.

Comment: Please reopen this question. Its unsolved. I am using Eclipse Photon 4.9 and out of the blue my SHIFT + 8 refused to work either. Workaround: SHIFT+CTRL+8 which adds () <-- Look, my keyboard works!!!
In Eclipse after resetting all keyboard shortcuts and restarting a few times no changes! I can´t make a ( in the Java Editor anymore. This is a bug!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `Window->Preference` see if there is any shortcut assign with `SHIFT + 8`, if its there just unbind it. 
See below image:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I tried this I found 2 records associated with this command. even I changed its short cuts unfortunately it didnt work for me.

Comment: remove it and restart your eclipse. see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, the default short cut for multi line comment is Shift + Ctrl + /.
You may wanna try that.

Comment: I am so sorry but multi line comment is not my purpose. Shift + 8 this combination is not working in eclipse that is my question.